# In jQuery closure, how to get window property descriptor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to see window property ‘otherName’ descriptor into jQuery closure. But 
    into jQuery closures 'otherName' descriptor is showing undefined, I think may 
    be getOwnPropertyDescriptor() did not get window object. Am i right? If I use 
    this code in plain js—

```
var otherName = "ckMe";
var result = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "otherName");
console.log(result); 
// Object { value: "ckMe", writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: 
//false }
```

This is fine. But when this code in jQuery, I have got result = undefined.

```
(function ($) {
  $(window).on("load", function (event) {
    var otherName = "ckMe";
    var result = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "otherName");
    console.log(result);//undefined
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Or if I use this code same result, undefined.

```
(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    var otherName = "ckMe";
    var result = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "otherName");
    console.log(result);//undefined
  });
}(jQuery));
```

I want to use this code in jQuery closure because my all codes in there. I 
was already searched this problem on google, but did not get any best 
solution. Please help me. Thanks to all. 
And sorry If I have anything wrong.

Comment: This feels like [an X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want the property descriptor?

Answer (score 1):

In your second two code blocks, `otherName` isn't a property of `window`. `window` only gets properties for `var` declarations at global scope. In your second two code blocks, the `var` declaration isn't at global scope, so `otherName` isn't a property of anything¹, it's just a local variable. They don't have property descriptors, because they aren't properties.

---

¹ *"isn't a property of anything"* - in specification terms, local variables are *bindings* on a Lexical Environment object. Bindings are a bit like properties, but they aren't properties (in the sense of JavaScript's object properties), and they don't have property descriptors (nor can you access the Lexical Environment object directly anyway — in fact, it may well not literally exist in any particular JavaScript engine).

Comment: I would assume that if the callbacks were named, this could be further illustrated by using the function name inside it in the place of the `window` and it would work

Comment: @Taplar: No, local variables are not properties of the function in which they're declared.

Comment: Interesting, I've not really used this method before.  I'm going to have to read up more.